# How do I get Rhythmbox to search also in the comment tag of MP3 files?

Tags: rhythmbox, search, id3

Rhythmbox can show the comment tag (ID3 tag), the checkbox under Preferences - General - Visible columns. But it **does not include the comment-field in the search**. Is there a way to include the comments in the search?